# Question a word problem of integrals

Tags: integration

$Let\int_a^bf dx = 3,\int_b^cf dx = 7, and \int_a^cgdx = 2.$

$Find
\int_a^c(
2f-3g) dx.$

so solving each integral with the given limits gives me 3 equations

$\int_a^bfdx=3$
solving first integral we get

$a^2/2+b^2/2=3 $
Or $a^2+b^2=6$

$\int_b^cf dx = 7$ solving second we get

$c^2/2 -b^2/2=7$ Or $c^2-b^2=14$

$\int_a^cgdx = 2$ solving 3rd we get

$c^2/2-a^2/2=2$ Or $c^2-a^2=4$

These three equations when solved simultaneously or through substitution will give us the values of a, b and c using these we can find the solution. I just want to confirm is my method correct before continuing on? (i do not have the answer key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_a^b f dx + \int_b^c f dx = \int_a^c f dx$$
$$m\int_a^c f dx + n\int_a^c g dx = \int_a^c (mf+ng) dx$$
Using these two facts you can get your answer. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you very much i instantly picked on your comment the moment i saw it

Answer (score 0):

$HINT$: integrals are linear operators, and they are aditive also, i.e. you can "glue" them and create a single integral out of two integrals with proper limits.